# Update MySQL table row

Tags: java, mysql

Hi, I wanted to add a Password change function to my programm. For that i need to update the password column of the specific user. I researched about it and fount this and tried it:

```
UPDATE uprtable SET password = '"+password+"' WHERE username = '"+username+"';
```

I also found out that i need to select the row after it. So I did this too.

```
SELECT username, password FROM uprtable WHERE username '"+username+"';
```

The Problem is it doesnt update it and I dont get any Errors where I could get any Info about what is wrong.
Here is the Code direct from the Class:

```
public void changepw() throws Exception{
        Connection con = getConnection();
        String passwordID1 = String.valueOf((passwordfield.getPassword()));
        String passwordID2 = String.valueOf((passwordfield2.getPassword()));
        String passwordID3 = String.valueOf((passwordfield3.getPassword()));
        if (passwordID1.equals(resultSet.getString("password"))) {
            if (passwordID2.equals(passwordID3)) {
                String userID = resultSet.getString("username");
                try {
                    PreparedStatement statementpwchange = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE uprtable SET password = '"+passwordID2+"' WHERE username = '"+userID+"'");
                    PreparedStatement statementpwchangeconfirm = con.prepareStatement("SELECT username, password, rank FROM uprtable WHERE username = '"+userID+"'");
                    System.out.println("Updated");
                    frame.dispose();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
            else {
                messageLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
                messageLabel.setText("The Passwords do not match");
            }
        }
    }
```

If you need more Information about the Code, feel free to ask.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're only preparing the statement - you also need to execute it.  Look here : https://www.javatpoint.com/PreparedStatement-interface .. note the 'execute' phrase.  Good luck :)

Comment: oh, and by the way - once you've executed your prepared statement, you don't need to select it for the update to 'stick'.

Comment: `username` is string and `userId` is Integer or Long, means `username != userId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have prepared the statement but have not executed the statement. For reference: **INSERT** (as well as **UPDATE** and **DELETE**) statements should use `executeUpdate()`.

**SELECT** statements should use `executeQuery()`.